# How to open a PFA csv file

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, data-science, opencsv

A client gave me a file in *CSV* format and called that *PFA*. I want to open a *PFA* file, but I got something like the one below.
I would appreciate it if I get help from you.

```py
df=pd.read_csv( '/home/mikaeil/Downloads/ccd4b28d-4340-4e4f-a3b4-e2de3a2de142.csv')
```

The result is like below:

```
0   f71069a5840386c6ece104de3f2bafc3ecb1ff37f1bc64...   99406be6f8f8044366aef3271ac4109d0538df39276e9e...   cb3e421b1d1c2c3448f323268f972ee3b2a54cc1021bf4...   3a14097e562c77b201d23978b706f07e52133506bf5902...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   e15274dcfe2d0cb541e8aa23fef7aaaa116bfcbc937d35...   ...     8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   c22cd1ea7268eed0a17f08b05559b6f7939040cf707d5a...   a416ea84421fa7e1351582da48235bac88380a337ec5cb...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   52ebab80b30e4922e932f30f2dd0de3a66dfccdc96c921...   1.0
1   f7e645ca1739c318ae12efa6767cf1e7f38accd55c238c...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   b690285b6e60662df771bc7a6b6ee1cb13f799e3d902ec...   ...     8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   26c9a96ce053a14dd88a71a4830c9cbed7e1fed7e3f3f8...   1.0
2   7a2987f600f343f47c4bd9c1bb704db28517da1e814f95...   ca9f6563c7614c5ef5f033c9aaa1aa21611412da771a91...   27e1c95e64999f594001f3b8fada27406bb96ae8adfded...   78df16cdd1a174c6372267773cf96fc1e7bbcc40a0e935...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   eb1e33e8a81b697b75855af6bfcdbcbf7cbbde9f94962c...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   ...     8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   8ab31b5afaea56114427e1f01b81d001b079a0f59539f6...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   648e5bca018ffe4b6db96361d9b1a5245ee72d27e49269...   1.0
3   e1eb1c05e9cd661690a5eca2566f93ff0a6146bd91025b...   9b2d5b4678781e53038e91ea5324530a03f27dc1d0e5f6...   4e07408562bedb8b60ce05c1decfe3ad16b72230967de0...   be683e560cde64bff281f929cab1c6588dc9b7057d3cbf...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   dc937b59892604f5a86ac96936cd7ff09e25f18ae6b758...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   8ce86a6ae65d3692e7305e2c58ac62eebd97d3d943e093...   3883138a87732955cea4ec542b22ef82c5342262ca1dab...   ...     8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   8aed642bf5118b9d3c859bd4be35ecac75b6e873cce34e...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   c72ae9676454d7cc0014583a9d0a2e28553d5c62f087c7...   a416ea84421fa7e1351582da48235bac88380a337ec5cb...   d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f...   1f4d86b1e0415f97659988ec13c7753c4bffc5f95d373c...   1.0
4   8e741abe8c2cdee489ce0b8c7fc3a87e726e66c858bed5...   ca9f6563c7614c5ef5f033c9aaa1aa21611412da771a91...
```

Comment: Please remove the image, put the code in this question inside a code block, tag python because it appears in the image to be related to python, and remember i in English is always capitalized as I.

Comment: In addition to above comment, as bare minimum specify what a `PFA CSV` is, and what you try to get from reading this file ?

Comment: A client gave it to me and said that it is an FPA file in CSV format. I searched on the internet but couldn't find much so I don't have also much information. I want to read this file and after that train a model with that to predict the future. If it is possible I could email file for you. It is just 250kb.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The result shown in the image might be the actual data in the csv. Can you open the csv with any other applications and share the result for the same?